# Get page background

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

How can I access the style information for a tab? The following code logs an empty object.

```
tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScript: 'self.port.emit(console.log(unsafeWindow.document.body.style);'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you are missing a `)` in your content script. Then you are returning the return value of `console.log` to the port.

However I am going to assume, that you are getting an empty object in the page's console from that `console.log`. The `document.body.style` attribute may still be empty, since that only holds the value of the *inline* style attribute of an HTML element (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

You would probably have to parse [document.styleSheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets) or use the [developer tools API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/dev_panel) to the get the currently rendered background.